# Do X-Server/X-Org come with the kernel?

Tags: kernel, xorg, xserver

Do X-Server/X-Org come with the kernel itself or are they separate packages that are installed in distributions? What is difference between Xorg and Xserver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xorg is merely the name for the project managing the suite of software for running an X11R6 server. Xorg is not part of the kernel though. It is a separate suite of libraries and applications, and can be built and run on not only the Linux kernel, but also runs on BSD, Darwin, Windows, and other platforms as well.